# Save login for several days

Tags: ios, authentication

I know how to save login info in the default user preference. But how to save the log in info for several days until the app ask the user to login again?

Comment: Related: This is something the OS should perform. The idea is you stuff it in the Keychain with an expiration date/time and the OS wipes it at expiry. Your program does not need to be run to ensure the wipe occurs.

Comment: Also see RADAR:20644404 and [Open RADAR 20644404](https://openradar.appspot.com/20644404). I've been meaning to file that feature request for some time. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You SHOULD NOT confidential data in user preferences, NEVER EVER EVER do this please. Apple can reject your app if this security issue is detected in app review.

Ok the better choice you have is to save those info in Keychain, the Keychain is a system secured database for this kind of usage (store confidential information).

[There is some info about KeyChain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html)

Also you can easy find some libs like [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) or play with [Generic Keychain example by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) to make things more easier, because KeyChain requires low level api to access and store data.

The interesting here is, if you use Keychain to store `username` and `password` for example, the app is able to *"remember"* even uninstalled and installed back by user. So you better is don't worry about the time, just try to log in with these credentials when needed.

Have a good lucky!

Comment: *"the app is able to "remember" even uninstalled"* - Oh, I was not aware of that, but I have experienced it. It never occurred to me that was by design. I have filed bug reports against Apple for retaining secrets that have been deleted.

Comment: Like at OSX, If an app put those secrets in Keychain, this info will be saved until the app remove secrets or user erase device data.

Comment: I encountered it on iOS. I deleted a mail server from the Mail app for testing. Later, I re-added the mail server and the credentials were still available. An app has no business retaining secrets that were deleted.